# Spring boot with MongoTemplate count aggregation with different set of conditions

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I have a collection where the document looks like below,

```
{
"id" : "1",
"age" : "86"
}
{
"id" : "2",
"age" : "30"
}
{
"id" : "3",
"age" : "35"
}
{
"id" : "4",
"age" : "76"
}
{
"id" : "5",
"age" : "52"
}
{
"id" : "6",
"age" : "53"
}
```

need to get below count result from above using SpringBoot MongoTemplate,

1. greater than 70
2. less than 40
3. between 40 and 70

expected result is,

```
{
"ageLT40" : 2,
"ageBW40to70" : 2,
"ageGT70":2
}
```

As of now i am doing three times to achieve this by using below query,

```
mongoTemplate.count(new Query().addCriteria(new Criteria().where("age").gt(70)),MyDocument.class);
mongoTemplate.count(new Query().addCriteria(new Criteria().where("age").lt(40)),MyDocument.class);
mongoTemplate.count(new Query().addCriteria(new Criteria().where("age").lt(70).and("age").gte("40"),MyDocument.class);
```

expecting query to avoid multiple DB hits

Answer (score 0):

This is to work with internal json objects of an array so it seems not possible to do this directly. I suggest use Jackson:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;// in play 2.3
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass[] myObjects = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass[].class);
```

and then do your summarizing in java and then do the templating

Comment: the collection is huge, loading it into java will affect performance